# CMD Echo Command Keeps Only Last Line of Text

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, echo, command-prompt

I'm creating a batch file and I'm having trouble with the following command:

```
    echo Hello & echo.World > Text.txt
```

Whenever I do this command the output only shows the last line, like so:

> World

But if I just do the above command in CMD without writing to a file, it appears perfectly in the command prompt. I have complete access over my file but I still can't seem to be able to write the whole text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In batch <kbd>&</kbd> is a command-separator. You can produce the same result by using two separate `echo` lines.

echo Hello & echo.World > Text.txt

executes as two independent commands,

echo Hello
   echo.World > Text.txt

which would report `Hello` to the console and write `World` to the file (you didn't mention that `Hello` appeared on the console...)

Note that <kbd>></kbd> creates a **new** file whereas <kbd>>></kbd> **appends** to any existing file (or creates a new file) so

```
echo Hello > Text.txt
echo.World > Text.txt
```

would first write `Hello` to a **new** file, then overwrite it with `World`.

To **append** the second line, you'd need

```
echo Hello > Text.txt
echo.World >> Text.txt
```

or, on one line,

```
echo Hello > Text.txt&echo.World >> Text.txt
```

A parenthesised statement-sequence (aka a "block") is regarded as one complex statement, so

```
(echo Hello &echo.World)> Text.txt
```

would create a new file containing both lines, whereas

```
(echo Hello &echo.World)>> Text.txt
```

would append the two lines to any existing file.

Note also that the trailing spaces before the <kbd>></kbd> will also be written to the file.

Be very careful about <kbd>></kbd> and <kbd>>></kbd>. if the command you execute is

```
echo Hello 1> Text.txt
```

then hello<kbd>Space</kbd> will be written to the file.

If a message terminating with <kbd>Space</kbd>*a single digit* is written to a file, then well, probably nothing will appear. When we have this situation, the digit immediately before the <kbd>></kbd> determins which 'logical device`output will be used. The useful ones here are 1 (standard output) and 2(standard error) so you can redirect errormessages using`2>errorreports.txt` for instance.

If you have this situation, you can overcome this characteristic by using

```
> Text.txt echo Hello 1
```

Answer (score 6):

In batch, the `>` operator has higher precedence than the `&` operator, so your example is only redirecting the last command `echo.World` to the file.  The first command is still outputting to the console.

To redirect multiple commands, you can surround them with parentheses.

```
(echo Hello & echo.World) > Text.txt
```